# Jsonify from def returning empty in python

Tags: python

I have def function, which return a query result as array and return jsonify, but it is returning empty

The def is

```
@app.route('/newsearchresults')
def newsearchresults():
        name = request.args.get('query')
        customers = {}
        customers = Customer.query.filter(Customer.name.like('%'+str(name)+'%')).all()
        return jsonify(customers)
```

the HTML form is this, which calls the jquery functions

```
<form action="/newsearchresults" >
  <Text  text="Customer Name" id="text0"/>
  <Input width="200px"  name="custName"  required  placeholder="Please enter the customer name"/>
  <button  type="submit">Search Customer</button>
 </form>
```

and the jquery script on Html file is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('form').on('submit', function()
          {
             name =$("input[name='custName']").val()
             $.get("/newsearchresults", {'query': name}).done(function (data)
            {

            });
```

I want to populate the jsonify response result to this table below in the same html file

```
<table border="1" >
            <tr><td><strong>Customer Id</strong></td><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td><strong>E Mail</strong></td> <td><strong>Mobile No</strong></td></tr>
             {% for name1 in customers %}
             <td><a class="customername" href="#" data-name="{{ name1.name }}">{{name1.id}}</a></td><td>{{name1.name}}</td><td>{{name1.email}}</td><td>{{name1.mobileno}}</td></tr>

             {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your are getting a non empty response from the query,

Comment: The def function is working fine before jsonify, but then it return jsonify is not working, returning empty.